# PHP alternate with 'secured' first element

Tags: php, wordpress

I need this for loop in WordPress, but I think also to the pure PHP will be ok.
I need to alternate my DIV, I have somethink like this:

```
// Here I getting total count of posts - return as INT, ex. 4
$countOffers = wp_count_posts( 'offer' )->publish;

<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php if ( $countOffers % 2 == 0 ): ?>
        // Align to left side
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/Offer/content', 'left' ); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        // Align to right side
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/Offer/content', 'right' ); ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php $countOffers--; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

It's working fine BUT, I want to 'secure' first element on left side.
This means that no matter how many items I return, it will always be the first on the left.

Comment: Can you just add a `float: left`' to these elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter variable for this(`$counter` in this example). In each iteration of the `while` loop check if `$counter` is divisible by 2 or not and align the element accordingly.

Your code should be like this:

```
$countOffers = wp_count_posts( 'offer' )->publish;
$counter = 1;
<?php while ($the_query->have_posts() && $counter <= $countOffers) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php if ( $counter % 2 != 0 ): ?>
        // Align to left side
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/Offer/content', 'left' ); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        // Align to right side
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/Offer/content', 'right' ); ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php ++$counter; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```